# Translating a sentence with "virisque"

Tags: latin-to-english-translation, grammar-identification

'Res Romana stat moribus antiquis virisque'

Please, help me to translate it, especially I have trouble understanding the grammar in the second part, *virisque* is from *vir* – 'man', so why here is *virisQUE*?

Comment: -que is a common enclitic that just means "and".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Viris* is indeed a form of *vir*, namely, the ablative plural, just like *moribus* and *antiquis*. The suffix *-que* is not a proper word in itself, but you can nevertheless look it up [in the dictionary](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/-que).

Long story short: adding *-que* to the end of a word is like putting an *et* in front of the word:

> Mater filiaque
> Mater et filia
> *Mother and daughter*

So your sentence could be read as:

> Res Romana stat moribus antiquis et viris

I have a hunch that the adjective *antiquis* applies to both nouns it agrees with, not just the first.

Comment: The OP asked for a translation: easily found on Latin-Phrases sites: "The Roman state stands with her ancient traditions & men (ancestors).", Ennius.